# Date formula in excel regarding calendar

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, calendar, date

I need to fill in a Day and Date column in an Excel table to create a one month calendar:

```
Select a year:  2016
Select a month: September

-------------------------
| Day      | Date       |
|------------------------
|Thursday  | 01.09.2016 |
|Friday    | 02.09.2016 |
|  etc.    |    etc.    |
-------------------------
```

(Note the date format is dd.mm.yyyy.)

The days and dates must be calculated automatically after choosing year and month.

Comment: What exactly do you need? Fill day and date?

Comment: Yes. To fill day and date but like it's in calendar for that month and year.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with a few simple formulas:

- Date for first day of the month:
  `=DATE(B1,B2,1)`
- Rest of the dates:
  `=IFERROR(IF(MONTH(B5)=MONTH(B5+1),B5+1,""),"")`
- Day names:
  `=IFERROR(CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(B5,2),"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),"")`

Fill the formulas down to 31 rows, it'll display only dates in the month, cells below will be empty.

[image]